# Specified cast is not valid, when using OleDbCommand

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

How it was working with excel

```
decimal LTLPrice = Decimal.Parse(sheet.get_Range("H27").Value.ToString());
decimal mathLTLPrice = Math.Round(LTLPrice, 2);
sheet.get_Range("C29").Value = SumToTextFormatProvider.SumToText(mathLTLPrice, "Lt", "ct");
```

How it should be in my imagination with OleDb

```
myCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$H27:H27]", MyConnection);
myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
while (myReader.Read())
{
    decimal LTLPrice = Decimal.Parse(myReader.GetString(0));
    decimal mathLTLPrice = Math.Round(LTLPrice, 2);
    myCommand = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Sheet1$C29:C29] SET F1='" + SumToTextFormatProvider.SumToText(mathLTLPrice, "Lt", "ct") + "'", MyConnection);
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
myReader.Close();
```

How it is

```
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
at System.Data.OleDb.ColumnBinding.ValueString()
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.GetString(Int32 ordinal)
at Trains.invoiceForm.invoiceGenerateXls_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Users\Nullified\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Trains\Trains\invoiceForm.cs:line 592
```

Error is in this line

```
decimal LTLPrice = Decimal.Parse(myReader.GetString(0));
```

Ive tried GetInt32 / GetDecimal but no result. :(

Update

With GetDouble i get no error, but myReader returns me 0, then in excel it is "3,49"

Comment: What is the value of myReader.GetString(0)?

Comment: Ive not checked "GetFieldType" first, now its fixed to GetDouble, but no luck - returning 0

Comment: can you try and see what you get for myReader[0].ToString() instead of myReader.GetString(0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, i am storing numbers as text in excel via oledb, and despite the fact that if we open xls file in excel we still can read it, and excel calculates everything normaly, oledb cant get correct double value from excel if it was calculated from numbers stored as text.
Now just left to find how to store double's in c# to excel as numbers, and problem will be solved.

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar issue, here is my fix applied to your question:

```
    decimal LTLPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(myReader.GetValue(0).ToString());
```

By grabbing the "value" you don't have to deal with the specifics on what your are pulling untill you try to do something with it.

Of course my problem was just a little different then yours in that I just had to convert everything to a string. Theroticly however this approach should still work for you as Convert.ToDecimal will work on strings if of course the value is convertable.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this code

```
if(myReader.GetString(0) != null)
{
    decimal LTLPrice = Decimal.Parse(myReader.GetString(0).Replace(",",".").Trim());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but ive not checked "myReader.GetFieldType" first, cell data is "Double", so GetString just isnt working.